# Spring transaction did not correctly rollback

Tags: java, spring, transactions

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@CustomTestContext
public class TransactionalTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    private Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    public void doSomething() {
        try {
            User user = new User();
            user.setUsername("test"); // username has unique constraint
            userRepository.save(user);
        } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
            logger.info("Wrong");
        }
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void doTest() {
        doSomething();
        doSomething();
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void doTest2() {
        doSomething();
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

When `doTest` ran into `DataIntegrityViolationException` in the second `doSomething` call, the first `doSomething` call did not rollback, which result in that user with username "test" still exists, and cause `doTest2`'s two `doSomethong` call throw `DataIntegrityViolationException`.

What I expect was when transactional method run into exception, it will rollback to the state before the first method with `@Transactional` annotation ran, which in the situation above is did not insert any new user to database at all, since the default propagation value is `REQUIRE`.

I turn the `JpaTransactionManager` logging level to `DEBUG` and got console like following:

```
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Creating new transaction with name [com.ray.spring.test.TransactionalTest.doTest]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Opened new EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@2ceca2ef]
INFO  o.s.t.c.t.TransactionContext                 - Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@3b42121d testClass = TransactionalTest, testInstance = com.ray.spring.test.TransactionalTest@7a2ab862, testMethod = doTest@TransactionalTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@41fa769c testClass = TransactionalTest, locations = '{file:src/main/resources/applicationContext.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{file:src/main/resources/application.properties}', propertySourceProperties = '{mysql.Url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springtest?characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimezone=UTC}', contextCustomizers = set[[empty]], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]]; transaction manager [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager@343e225a]; rollback [true]
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Participating in existing transaction
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL                            - insert into User (password, username) values (?, ?)
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[com.ray.spring.model.User#1]],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Participating in existing transaction
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL                            - insert into User (password, username) values (?, ?)
WARN  o.h.e.j.spi.SqlExceptionHelper               - SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
ERROR o.h.e.j.spi.SqlExceptionHelper               - Duplicate entry 'test' for key 'UK_jreodf78a7pl5qidfh43axdfb'
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Participating transaction failed - marking existing transaction as rollback-only
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Setting JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[com.ray.spring.model.User#1]],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] rollback-only
INFO  c.r.s.test.TransactionalTest                 - Wrong
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Initiating transaction rollback
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Rolling back JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[com.ray.spring.model.User#1]],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])]
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Closing JPA EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] after transaction
INFO  o.s.t.c.t.TransactionContext                 - Rolled back transaction for test context [DefaultTestContext@3b42121d testClass = TransactionalTest, testInstance = com.ray.spring.test.TransactionalTest@7a2ab862, testMethod = doTest@TransactionalTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@41fa769c testClass = TransactionalTest, locations = '{file:src/main/resources/applicationContext.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{file:src/main/resources/application.properties}', propertySourceProperties = '{mysql.Url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springtest?characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimezone=UTC}', contextCustomizers = set[[empty]], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]].
// doTest2() below
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Creating new transaction with name [com.ray.spring.test.TransactionalTest.doTest2]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Opened new EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@17229821]
INFO  o.s.t.c.t.TransactionContext                 - Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@3b42121d testClass = TransactionalTest, testInstance = com.ray.spring.test.TransactionalTest@e829999, testMethod = doTest2@TransactionalTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@41fa769c testClass = TransactionalTest, locations = '{file:src/main/resources/applicationContext.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{file:src/main/resources/application.properties}', propertySourceProperties = '{mysql.Url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springtest?characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimezone=UTC}', contextCustomizers = set[[empty]], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]]; transaction manager [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager@343e225a]; rollback [true]
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Participating in existing transaction
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL                            - insert into User (password, username) values (?, ?)
WARN  o.h.e.j.spi.SqlExceptionHelper               - SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
ERROR o.h.e.j.spi.SqlExceptionHelper               - Duplicate entry 'test' for key 'UK_jreodf78a7pl5qidfh43axdfb'
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Participating transaction failed - marking existing transaction as rollback-only
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Setting JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] rollback-only
INFO  c.r.s.test.TransactionalTest                 - Wrong
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Participating in existing transaction
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL                            - insert into User (password, username) values (?, ?)
WARN  o.h.e.j.spi.SqlExceptionHelper               - SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
ERROR o.h.e.j.spi.SqlExceptionHelper               - Duplicate entry 'test' for key 'UK_jreodf78a7pl5qidfh43axdfb'
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Participating transaction failed - marking existing transaction as rollback-only
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Setting JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] rollback-only
INFO  c.r.s.test.TransactionalTest                 - Wrong
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Initiating transaction rollback
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Rolling back JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])]
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Closing JPA EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] after transaction
INFO  o.s.t.c.t.TransactionContext                 - Rolled back transaction for test context [DefaultTestContext@3b42121d testClass = TransactionalTest, testInstance = com.ray.spring.test.TransactionalTest@e829999, testMethod = doTest2@TransactionalTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@41fa769c testClass = TransactionalTest, locations = '{file:src/main/resources/applicationContext.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{file:src/main/resources/application.properties}', propertySourceProperties = '{mysql.Url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springtest?characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimezone=UTC}', contextCustomizers = set[[empty]], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]].
```

Seems it did rollback but not affect the first `doSomething` call.

Update:

I edit my code as follow:

```
@Transactional
public void doSomething() {
    logger.info("First save");
    userRepository.save(new User("test", "test"));
    logger.info("Second save");
    userRepository.save(new User("test", "test"));
}

@Test
@Transactional
public void doTest() {
    doSomething();
}

@Test
@Transactional
public void doTest2() {
    doSomething();
}
```

I've add `@transactional` to `doSomething()` and let exception throw from `doSomething`, but got the same result:

```
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Creating new transaction with name [com.ray.spring.test.TransactionalTest.doTest]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Opened new EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@42d6c12d]
INFO  o.s.t.c.t.TransactionContext                 - Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@7a2ab862 testClass = TransactionalTest, testInstance = com.ray.spring.test.TransactionalTest@33188612, testMethod = doTest@TransactionalTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@40113163 testClass = TransactionalTest, locations = '{file:src/main/resources/applicationContext.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{file:src/main/resources/application.properties}', propertySourceProperties = '{mysql.Url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springtest?characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimezone=UTC}', contextCustomizers = set[[empty]], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]]; transaction manager [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager@1a07bf6]; rollback [true]
INFO  c.r.s.test.TransactionalTest                 - First save
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Participating in existing transaction
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL                            - insert into User (password, username) values (?, ?)
INFO  c.r.s.test.TransactionalTest                 - Second save
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[com.ray.spring.model.User#1]],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Participating in existing transaction
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL                            - insert into User (password, username) values (?, ?)
WARN  o.h.e.j.spi.SqlExceptionHelper               - SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
ERROR o.h.e.j.spi.SqlExceptionHelper               - Duplicate entry 'test' for key 'UK_jreodf78a7pl5qidfh43axdfb'
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Participating transaction failed - marking existing transaction as rollback-only
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Setting JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[com.ray.spring.model.User#1]],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] rollback-only
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Initiating transaction rollback
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Rolling back JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[com.ray.spring.model.User#1]],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])]
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Closing JPA EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] after transaction
INFO  o.s.t.c.t.TransactionContext                 - Rolled back transaction for test context [DefaultTestContext@7a2ab862 testClass = TransactionalTest, testInstance = com.ray.spring.test.TransactionalTest@33188612, testMethod = doTest@TransactionalTest, testException = org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [UK_jreodf78a7pl5qidfh43axdfb]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement, mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@40113163 testClass = TransactionalTest, locations = '{file:src/main/resources/applicationContext.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{file:src/main/resources/application.properties}', propertySourceProperties = '{mysql.Url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springtest?characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimezone=UTC}', contextCustomizers = set[[empty]], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]].
\\ doTest2() below
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Creating new transaction with name [com.ray.spring.test.TransactionalTest.doTest2]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Opened new EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@22d9ca63]
INFO  o.s.t.c.t.TransactionContext                 - Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@7a2ab862 testClass = TransactionalTest, testInstance = com.ray.spring.test.TransactionalTest@484149eb, testMethod = doTest2@TransactionalTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@40113163 testClass = TransactionalTest, locations = '{file:src/main/resources/applicationContext.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{file:src/main/resources/application.properties}', propertySourceProperties = '{mysql.Url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springtest?characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimezone=UTC}', contextCustomizers = set[[empty]], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]]; transaction manager [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager@1a07bf6]; rollback [true]
INFO  c.r.s.test.TransactionalTest                 - First save
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Participating in existing transaction
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL                            - insert into User (password, username) values (?, ?)
WARN  o.h.e.j.spi.SqlExceptionHelper               - SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
ERROR o.h.e.j.spi.SqlExceptionHelper               - Duplicate entry 'test' for key 'UK_jreodf78a7pl5qidfh43axdfb'
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Participating transaction failed - marking existing transaction as rollback-only
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Setting JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] rollback-only
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Initiating transaction rollback
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Rolling back JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])]
DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager              - Closing JPA EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] after transaction
INFO  o.s.t.c.t.TransactionContext                 - Rolled back transaction for test context [DefaultTestContext@7a2ab862 testClass = TransactionalTest, testInstance = com.ray.spring.test.TransactionalTest@484149eb, testMethod = doTest2@TransactionalTest, testException = org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [UK_jreodf78a7pl5qidfh43axdfb]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement, mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@40113163 testClass = TransactionalTest, locations = '{file:src/main/resources/applicationContext.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{file:src/main/resources/application.properties}', propertySourceProperties = '{mysql.Url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springtest?characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimezone=UTC}', contextCustomizers = set[[empty]], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]].
```

It has the line `Participating transaction failed - marking existing transaction as rollback-only`, but the `doTest2` still failed at the first `userRepository.save()` try, means that user with "test" name already exists.

Is it means the first `save` could not be rollbacked when some exception happened inside the same transaction?

CustomTestContxt.java

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@ContextConfiguration("file:src/main/resources/applicationContext.xml")
@TestPropertySource(
        locations = {"file:src/main/resources/application.properties"},
        properties = {"mysql.Url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springtest?characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimezone=UTC"})
public @interface CustomTestContext {
}
```

update2:

```
@Test
@Transactional
@Rollback
public void doTest() {
    entityManager.persist(new User("test", "test"));
}

@Test
@Tranactional
public void doTest2() {
    logger.info(entityManager.find(User.class, 1L));
}
```

And it log:

```
INFO  c.r.s.test.TransactionalTest          - User{id=1, username='test', password='test', roles=[]}
```

Answer (score 0):

doSomething() is catching the exception.

The transaction will only be rolled back when a RuntimeException is thrown in a method annoated with @Transactional.

If you want to leave the code as it is you must manually rollback the transaction in doSomething()

```
TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
```

The second option is to mark doSomething() as transactional and then NOT catch the transaction. Then the transaction handling must be done in the test methods.

Comment: Can you please give more information how CustomTestContext looks like?

Comment: `@CustomTestContext` is a shortcut for define a `@TestPropertySource` with test `datasource` definition. I've updated to question.

Comment: I don't see your problem now. The transactions are rolldback both

Comment: I want the `user` table which `userRepository` served as data access layer to be empty every time I ended up a `@Test` method to make tests isolated, as I read from Spring doc, tests with `@Transactional` will automatically roll back after test method return. The problem is, in my code  snippet, `doTest2` start with an entry in `user` table which result in `DataIntegrityViolationException` in the first `save` try, proved that previous test(`doTest`) did not roll back and delete the saved `User` object from database.

Comment: I've update a more clear version of code of my intention, Do I misunderstand the Spring's `rollback` with a real database `rollback` SQL statement?

Comment: I still don't understand. persist will insert the database but rollback will rollback the transaction. What's the problem?

Comment: You mean rollback the transaction will not perform like `delete from user u where u.id = 1` (assume previous inserted user entry has an ID 1)?

Comment: No. rollback will undo all changes in the database. there is no statement you can see about that. https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-acid-and-database-transactions/

Comment: But after a rollback in doTest() , doTest2() still can get user with id of 1 which was the inserted user from database, did it mean that the insert operation have not been undo?

Comment: are you sure that this is the user from the DB? Is the DB empty before you start your test

Comment: After switching my project to `spring-boot`, I got the right result under `spring-boot`'s autoconfigure, looks like it's something wrong within my manual config.